# Stack discrete columns in excel 5 columns at a time

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have 7 sets of 5 columns with similar data. Currently, I manually copy and paste each 5-column set below the previous set so that all 7 sets are in 5 columns. I need a macro that will turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

This macro works well for stacking multiple columns into just one column, but I can't get it to work for 5 columns at a time:

```
Sub CombineColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lastCell As Integer

Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.Count
    Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count
Next iCol
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim FinalArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim zz As Long
Dim PosSet As Long
Dim rngDestiny As Range

Set rngDestiny = Range("A14") 'Change this to top left cell of data destiny


MiMatriz = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value 'A1 is top left cell of complete dataset

ReDim FinalArray(1 To Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1, 1 To 5) As Variant

For zz = 1 To 5 Step 1
    PosSet = 0
    Do Until 1 + PosSet > UBound(FinalArray) - 1
        For i = 2 To 6 Step 1
            FinalArray(i + PosSet, zz) = MiMatriz(i, zz + PosSet)
        Next i
        PosSet = PosSet + 5
    Loop
Next zz

'add headers in index 1

FinalArray(1, 1) = "Title 1"
FinalArray(1, 2) = "Title 2"
FinalArray(1, 3) = "Title 3"
FinalArray(1, 4) = "Title 4"
FinalArray(1, 5) = "Title 5"

'paste data
rngDestiny.Resize(UBound(FinalArray), 5).Value = FinalArray

Erase FinalArray, MiMatriz
End Sub
```

This is how it works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in `Power Query` available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

**Algorithm**

- Demote the header row
- Transpose the table
- Split the table into "pages" where each "page" has the same number of rows as the desired number of columns
- Transpose each subtable, removing the first row from all except the very first subtable

  - *The first row of each subtable is the original column header, but we only want to retain the headers of the first five columns*
- Expand the subtables into one, and promote the first row to the Header position

To enter this code:

- Select some cell in the original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- In the Power Query Editor: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- In that window, examine Line 2 and record the actual Table Name
- Paste the M Code below into that window, replacing what is there
- Edit Line 2 to reflect the actual Table Name
- Examine the code, comments, and the Applied Steps window to understand what is going on.
- Close and Load

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

//Demote headers and transpose
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),

//split rows into tables of what will be number of columns
// pagesize argument <= number of columns "5"
    #"Split into Separate Tables" = Table.FromList(
        Table.Split(#"Transposed Table",5),
        Splitter.SplitByNothing(),null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

//Transpose the subtables
//   Except for first table, delete the first row after transposing:
//      That would be the old column headers
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split into Separate Tables", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each 
        if [Index] = 0 then Table.Transpose([Column1])
        else Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.Transpose([Column1]))),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Index"}),

//Expand the tables and promote first row to header row
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", 
        {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Expanded Custom", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//Set the types to text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
        {{"Title 1", type text}, {"Title 2", type text}, {"Title 3", type text}, {"Title 4", type text}, {"Title 5", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]